# How to call method of all custom UIView in a ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

I created a custom UIView with a UIButton inside
When I click on it, it simple changes its background color.

I would like to know how to change the background color of this button in all the instances of this custom UIView.

Any idea?

```
import UIKit

class RadioChannelView: UIView {

    var playButton:UIButton!

    init(frame: CGRect, themeColor: UIColor) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        playButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
        playButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        playButton.layer.cornerRadius = 40

        playButton.addTarget(self, action: "playButtonTapped", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func playButtonTapped() {
        self.playButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }

}
```

Comment: you have to loop through all subviews and change the background color for that button.

Comment: You can do `UIButton.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([RadioChannelView.self]).backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()`

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is to add your `RadioChannelView` class as an observer to the `NSNotificationCenter`. On button click post your notification to the observers, in turn it wakes listener method of this notification where you can change the background.

```
class RadioChannelView: UIView {

    var playButton:UIButton!

    init(frame: CGRect, themeColor: UIColor) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        playButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
        playButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        playButton.layer.cornerRadius = 40

        playButton.addTarget(self, action: "playButtonTapped", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "didReceiveBtnClickNotification:", name: "button_clicked", object: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func playButtonTapped() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("button_clicked", object: nil);
    }

    func didReceiveBtnClickNotification(sender: NSNotification!) {
        self.playButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
}
```